# IIS Express and asp.net 1.0.0-Beta8

Tags: iis-express, asp.net-core-mvc

after updating my test project to beta8 (not without a huge pain), I finally managed to have my project up and running.

Now, every time I try to debug with IISExpress, I have explicitly point to the page "index.html" and this breaks my angularjs app.

There is a way to map index.html as default document in IIS Express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to properly configure the middleware:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
```

It has some overrides if you need them. You can find more details [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html).